# Page controls do not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my design part I have added all labels and Dropdown lists but in register.aspx.cs, it shows these controls do not exist in the current context..

```
    using System;    
    using System.Collections;    
    using System.Configuration;    
    using System.Data;    
    using System.Linq;    
    using System.Web;    
    using System.Web.Security;    
    using System.Web.UI;    
    using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;    
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;    
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;     
    using System.Xml.Linq;    
    using System.Data.SqlClient;  
    using System.IO;


    public partial class register : System.Web.UI.Page    
    {    
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server = .\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFileName    =|DataDirectory|\\Database123.mdf;trusted_connection = true;USER Instance =yes");    
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }



    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        try
        {

            if (CheckBox1.Checked == true)
            {
                String f;
                f = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
                con.Open();
                if (f != "")
                {

                    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~") + "/images/" + f);
                    Label2.Text = "~" + "/images/" + f;

                    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("insert into register values('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox8.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "','" + RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue + "','" + TextBox4.Text + "','" + DropDownList3.SelectedItem + "','" + DropDownList2.SelectedItem + "','" + TextBox7.Text + "','" + TextBox10.Text + "','" + RadioButtonList2.SelectedValue + "','" + TextBox12.Text + "','" + Label2.Text + "','" + DropDownList1.Text + "','" + TextBox14.Text + "')", con);
                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    TextBox1.Text = " ";
                    TextBox8.Text = " ";
                    TextBox2.Text = " ";
                    TextBox3.Text = " ";
                    TextBox4.Text = " ";
                    // TextBox15.Text = " ";
                    // TextBox16.Text = " ";
                    TextBox7.Text = " ";
                    TextBox10.Text = " ";
                    TextBox12.Text = " ";
                    TextBox14.Text = " ";

                    Label1.Visible = true;
                    Label1.Text = "submitted successfully";
                }

                else
                {

                    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("insert into register(user_id,password,fname,lname,user_type,address,city,state,pin,contact_no,gender,email,seq_que,seq_ans) values('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox8.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "','" + RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue + "','" + TextBox4.Text + "','" + DropDownList3.SelectedItem + "','" + DropDownList2.SelectedItem + "','" + TextBox7.Text + "','" + TextBox10.Text + "','" + RadioButtonList2.SelectedValue + "','" + TextBox12.Text + "','" + DropDownList1.Text + "','" + TextBox14.Text + "')", con);
                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    TextBox1.Text = " ";
                    TextBox8.Text = " ";
                    TextBox2.Text = " ";
                    TextBox3.Text = " ";
                    TextBox4.Text = " ";
                    // TextBox15.Text = " ";
                    //TextBox16.Text = " ";
                    TextBox7.Text = " ";
                    TextBox10.Text = " ";
                    TextBox12.Text = " ";
                    TextBox14.Text = " ";

                    Label1.Visible = true;
                    Label1.Text = "submitted successfully";
                }
                con.Close();

            }
            else
            {
                Label1.Visible = true;
                Label1.Text = " terms & condition must checked";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert(\"Invalid Data Entry\")</script>");
        }

        }
    protected void  DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    if (DropDownList2.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            DropDownList3.Items.Clear();
            DropDownList3.Items.Add("jaipur");
            DropDownList3.Items.Add("udaipur");
            DropDownList3.Items.Add("ajmer");
            DropDownList3.Items.Add("bharatpur");
            DropDownList3.Items.Add("tonk");
        }
        else if (DropDownList2.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
            DropDownList3.Items.Clear();
            DropDownList3.Items.Add("amravati");
            DropDownList3.Items.Add("mumbai");

        }
    }

    protected void DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    }
```

Comment: Please supply the aspx file too and remove all code but 1 textbox so its easier to help and debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have correctly specified the code behind file in the page directive and still if you are facing with the same issue, may be your page designer (`register.aspx.designer.cs`) got messed up. You can delete and recreate it.

1) First delete `register.aspx.designer.cs`

2) Then right click on the web project from the Solution Explorer and select the option `Convert to Web Application` (this would recreate the desginer.cs; now it should work fine)

Comment: @user949914 great. FYI: if it answered your question you can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Inherits property on the aspx page
mentioned in Aphelion's answer
and also ensure the proper closing of tags on the aspx page

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Aspx page correctly sets the `CodeFile` and `Inherits` properties.

Aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Register.aspx.cs" Inherits="register" %>
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class register : System.Web.UI.Page {}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you copy elements from a different version of vs and paste it to your app you may experience this problem. Just delete those elements and add them back using the toolbox in vs.